# How to handle Pinch and Pan Gesture UIView inside UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

could anyone tell me how to handle Pinch and pan gesture UIView inside UIScrollview. 
I have to display both 2 videos at the same time and can use pan and pinch gesture on it.So I keep both AVPlayer on each of its UIView. Then I put that UIView inside each of ScrollView.
Now I need even when I pan or pinch that UIView it still keeps inside the UIScrollView's bound corner. Because when I panned it I can move it outside of the UIScrollview.
Here is my code in github
https://github.com/longnh2604/CheckVideoZoom.git

> Pan gesture

```
- (IBAction)handlePan1:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

> Pinch gesture

```
- (void)twoFingerPinch1:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    static float initialDifference = 0.0;
    static float oldScale = 1.0;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        initialDifference = oldScale - recognizer.scale;
    }

    CGFloat scale = oldScale - (oldScale - recognizer.scale) + initialDifference;

    viewVideo1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, scale, scale);

    oldScale = scale;

}
```